# Ruby - Parsing '(3)' to integer returns 0

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, integer, brackets

I'm trying to get integer from string `'(3)'`. However method `to_i` returns `0`. 
It seems that brackets with quotes cause the problem, but I don't understand the reason.

```
'3'.to_i => 3
(3).to_i => 3
'(3)'.to_i => 0
```

Why does it happen and how to solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#to_i` ignores trailing (non numeric) characters:

```
"3foo".to_i         #=> 3
"3)".to_i           #=> 3
```

Leading (non numeric) characters don't work and return `0`:

```
"foo3".to_i         #=> 0
"(3".to_i           #=> 0
```

You can extract the integer part using a regular expression:

```
"(3)"[/-?\d+/]      #=> "3"
```

And convert that to an integer:

```
"(3)"[/-?\d+/].to_i #=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`(3)` is an expression, not a string; it evaluates to a *number* `3`.

`'3'` is a string literal, it doesn't evaluate to any number, but can be cast to it with `to_i`. The rules are [quite simple](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i):

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an
>   integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the
>   end of a valid number are ignored. **If there is not a valid number at
>   the start of str, 0 is returned.** This method never raises an exception
>   when base is valid.

`'(3)'` is another string literal, again it doesn't evaluate to any number by itself. The problem is that you won't be able to make the parser 'understand' somehow that `(` in the beginning of this particular string should be treated as a separator - and essentially ignored. That's not how it works.

One possible solution is to replace the `(` symbol at the beginning of the string with `sub` (as trailing non-digit symbols are ignored by `to_i`):

```
'(3)'.sub(/^\(/, '').to_i => 3
```

But I really wonder why do you get the parenthesis in the first place here.

Comment: Thank you for exhaustive explanation. (I admit I could look to documentation, I thought to_i handles strings like that). Use of parenthesis is just an aesthetic issue, no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

`(3)` is a *Ruby expression*, and `'(3)'.to_i` doesn't work for the same reason that `'Math.sqrt(9)'.to_i` doesn't work.

If it helps, you can use a regexp to pick out the part of the string that *is* a number, and convert that

```
puts '(3)'[/\d+/].to_i
```

**output**

```
3
```